# Permission denied when trying to uninstal ruby 2.2.1 using rvm uninstall 2.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using OS X Yosemite version 10.10.4 and I'm new to ruby and rails. Trying to build a test app for a udemy class I'm taking and can't uninstall ruby to start over.

```
rm: /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/test/zoneinfo: Permission denied
rm: /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/test: Permission denied
rm: /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/tzinfo.gemspec: Permission denied
rm: /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib: Directory not empty
rm: /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1: Directory not empty
++ typeset ret=1
++ rvm_debug '__rvm_rm_rf error removing target dir    '\''/Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1'\''.'
++ ((  0  ))
++ return 0
++ return 1
```

Comment: check permissions `ls -l /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/tzinfo-1.2.2/test/zoneinfo`

Comment: This is what I got...

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x  3 root  staff    102 Aug 29 23:28 Australia`  
    `-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff    127 Aug 29 23:28 EST`  
    `drwxr-xr-x  3 root  staff    102 Aug 29 23:28 Etc`  
    `drwxr-xr-x  7 root  staff    238 Aug 29 23:28 Europe`  
    `-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff    264 Aug 29 23:28 Factory`  
    `-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   4554 Aug 29 23:28 iso3166.tab`  
    `drwxr-xr-x  3 root  staff    102 Aug 29 23:28 posix`  
    `-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff   3545 Aug 29 23:28 posixrules`

Comment: those files owned by root, this is probably because you've installed tzinfo as root and this is probably not the only gem with such issue. you can fix it at once by changing owner for all .rvm dir to be sure: `sudo chown -R thomascalhoun /Users/thomascalhoun/.rvm/`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Bless you!